# Deleting Nodes and Relationships without deleting the parent node in Neo4J 2.0

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a requirement to delete *ALL* nodes and relationships from a parent/root node and NOT delete the parent/root node.
The graph Database contains 2 labels (User and Contact) to group the nodes.

Currently I am able accomplish this with the following script, where '6' is the parent/node

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r]-(c:Contact) 
WHERE u.email = 'nouser@noserver.com' AND ID(c) > 6 
DELETE c, r
```

Is there a better way to do this?
Is there a way to tell Neo4J not to delete the parent/root node?

Comment: Did you mean `ID(c) <> 6`?

Answer (score 0):

That's a good way, what is your issue with it?

You told Neo4j *not* to delete the User node.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that I have to know the node id. I was hoping to just match a property on the parent node to identify it vs. node id.

Something like this:

MATCH (u:User)-[r]-(c:Contact) 
WHERE u.email = 'nouser@noserver.com' AND NOT u.mail = 'nouser@noserver.com'
DELETE c, r

Which does not seem to work, any suggestions ?